# SQL Server DDL trigger on drop table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, ddl-trigger

I have a database with few tables: tab1, tab2, tab3. How can I create a DDL trigger on drop table **only for tab2** (not for tab1 and tab3). When `drop tab2` is called I need to update values in this table but not to delete tab2. How can I do this? I found this but don't understand how it works:

```
create trigger trDatabse_OnDropTable
on database
for drop_table
as
begin
 set nocount on;
 select
  'Table dropped: ' +
  quotename(eventdata().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]', 'sysname')) + N'.' +
  quotename(eventdata().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'sysname'));
end;
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can prevent a `DROP` using a trigger, just react to it having been done (ie just an `AFTER` trigger)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: guess you'd have to `DENY` the permission to `DROP` to prevent this from happening ....

Comment: @marc_s Yes, that'd prevent the drop, but also probably prevent the trigger from firing to do the updates.

Comment: You **can** prevent a `DROP TABLE` statement using a DDL Trigger.  As noted in the answer from @Sven, DDL Trigger events can be rolled back.  The use of a `DENY` permission would not be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this article [DDL Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941.aspx) you'll find that there are no INSTEAD OF DDL Triggers, like in DML Triggers, so you can't prevent the drop and execute your own command instead:

> DDL triggers fire only after the DDL statements that trigger them are
>   run. DDL triggers cannot be used as INSTEAD OF triggers. DDL triggers
>   do not fire in response to events that affect local or global
>   temporary tables and stored procedures.

This piece of code you posted is for logging DROP TABLE event. `eventdata()` contains XML with some information on the event: LoginName, ObjectName, TSQLCommand, PostTime and many more.

Comment: Actually you can prevent the `DROP TABLE` command. DDL events associated with DDL triggers are transacted operations and can be rolled back. @Sven shows this in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent deletion of a table with ddl trigger. Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER drop_safe 
ON DATABASE 
FOR DROP_TABLE 
AS 
   PRINT 'You must disable Trigger "drop_safe" to drop table!' 
   ROLLBACK
;
```

To only prevent deletion on your specified table you have to look at the eventdata() and ROLLBACK only in that special case.

Answer (score 3):

```
create trigger trDatabse_OnDropTable
on database
for drop_table
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    --Get the table schema and table name from EVENTDATA()
    DECLARE @Schema SYSNAME = eventdata().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]', 'sysname');
    DECLARE @Table SYSNAME = eventdata().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'sysname');

    IF @Schema = 'dbo' AND @Table = 'tab2'
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'DROP TABLE Issued.';

        --Optional: error message for end user.
        RAISERROR ('[dbo].[tab2] cannot be dropped.', 16, 1);

        --Rollback transaction for the DROP TABLE statement that fired the DDL trigger
        ROLLBACK;

        --Run your update after the ROLLBACK
        BEGIN TRAN
            UPDATE dbo.tab2
            SET ... ;
        COMMIT;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        --Do nothing.  Allow table to be dropped.
        PRINT 'Table dropped: [' + @Schema + '].[' + @Table + ']';
    END
end;
```